# avoid using "source" to set an environment?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to set a bunch of environment variables in my env.
What I'm used to do is:

```
source ./script
```

But now I want my script to be in the PATH variable so I can call it from everywhere I want.

But calling it like that:

```
script
```

Will open a new shell and set the variables in the new shell, once the script is finished executing, I'd lose everything.

So I was wondering how I could do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you should use an `alias`.

Say your environment variables are in the file `/path/to/stuff/my_env`, just add an alias

```
alias my_env="source /path/to/stuff/my_env"
```

Then you just need to issue `my_env` and you'll be done!

What you're trying to achieve can't be done from within a script, unless your script launches a new `bash` command, but that's a bit awkward!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that sources the script:

```
do_it () {
  source /your/script
}
```

Put that in your `.bashrc` and you can just issue

```
do_it
```